# Android BLE out of band data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been working on a BLE sensor app. I set my sensor to send an OOB key during pairing but I'm not sure what to do on Android SDK side in order to make my App request the OOB when we call create bond in the code.

If I switch my sensor to Keyboard capable I see that Android is requesting a random pin. But I don't want to use the pin I would like to use OOB.

Basically, my sensor and Android app have the knowledge of a OOB secret key and I would like for bonding to be established based on this secret key.

Comment: Hello @Gilson Did you find an answer for your question?